# Counting and Grouping function with Python (2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

**I have tried the following function:**

```
def item_order(order):
    salads = order.count("salad")
    hamburgers = order.count("hamburger")
    waters = order.count("water")
    return "salad:{} hamburger:{} water:{}".format(salads, hamburgers, waters)
```

taken from ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906570/counting-and-grouping-with-python ), 
with these two orders:

1st order = "salad water hamburger salad hamburger" 
- then the function should returns "salad:2 hamburger:2 water:1"  
 
2nd order = "hamburger water hamburger" 
then the function should returns "salad:0 hamburger:2 water:1",

in http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

But it seems it doesn't work.
Maintaining this structure, what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks for any help!!

Comment: Your function works fine for me. What is the error you are getting? "it seems it doesn't work" is a weak description of the problem.

Comment: also works for me. is the problem how you are calling the function? (that is, is the problem in some aspect outside the function definition, and not shown here?)

Comment: Thanks for your comments!
Here is the structure in Pythontutor.com:
http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#togetherjs=F8x7yv079Q

I can see just two steps, and then the tutor stops without returning the printed result

Comment: Thanks @Wacky Whale, for your help! and to all of you guys, for your comments.
Now is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function definition, and then in your script you define the order:

```
def item_order(order):
    # your function here

order = 'salad water hamburger salad hamburger'
```

When you call the function, you need to either assign the result to a variable or otherwise display the return from the function. So:

```
print item_order(order)
```

or:

```
x = item_order(order)
print x
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Stidgeon,for your kind answer, now is working!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as intended. 
Variable order needs to be assigned some value and then function item_order can be called with variable order as the argument.